# How do i remove comments from config.js file

Tags: javascript, json, npm, strip

How do i remove comments from config.js file it act as JSON file in my project.
In my config file i have single line comments like this

```
//comment goes here
```

and multi line comments like this

```
/* comments goes here */
```

so i am using **strip-json-comments** to remove comments.
I installed it as globally using following command

```
npm install --global strip-json-comments
```

But the problem is whenever i am trying run this command in Node command i am getting error

```
strip-json-comments config.js  > config_comments_removed.js
```

**Error is**

```
'strip-json-comments' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.
```

Please help me to get out of this problem 
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Why complicate things? Try a website like:

http://www.httputility.net/json-minifier.aspx

Comment: you can also remove comments using grep command

Comment: @FelixWeir as a requirement i have to use this

Comment: @FelixWeir in the process of generating  build all the things are automated, so i am using this command in my build generating process in grunt file, so i need to use this.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing [`strip-json-comments-cli`](https://github.com/sindresorhus/strip-json-comments-cli) instead. `strip-json-comments` does not come with a CLI utility.

Comment: i installed what you have said but i am getting error

Comment: Error: ** const fs = require('fs');
^^^^^
SyntaxError: Use of const in strict mode.
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:73:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:443:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
    at startup (node.js:129:16)
    at node.js:814:3 **

Comment: @MahiKalyanar It is unclear to me what module exactly is throwing that error and whether or not it is the fault of the module itself.